# python jupyter coding confusion

Tags: python

I got some python course on udemy but whole course is in jupyter,my question is what is difference bewteen .py coding and .ipynb?why course is in jupyer but everyone on  youtube coding in VsCode/Pycharm/Sublime without jupyer notebook integration

for example in jupyter

```
a = 20 
a
```

and you will get result but in VsCode nothing happens you must Create New Jupyter Notebook integration for that.
It is the same result you will get but with different coding(.py/.ipynb) or i am missing something?

Comment: I think I've answered this issue before, but I can't locate the duplicate.  Can anyone else dig up a prior explanation?

Comment: There's no functional difference between jupyter and python coding, well for the most part. I think, for courses why jupyter is preferred is because of how it gives the user feedback. It's easier to put logically separate modules/functionalities into different cells for breaking down stuffs, and ask the users to modify specific cells to achieve desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the difference between using interactive mode and script mode.
Jupyter is an IDE (Interactive Development Environment).  One of the features is that when you enter an expression, the interpreter prints that value.  A formal Python script doesn't display unless you explicitly tell it to do so with the `print` method.  To get your value displayed, use

```
a = 20
print(a)
```

Comment: Along those lines, OP might be interested that the "model is often called a REPL, or Read-Eval-Print-Loop", see [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/development/how_ipython_works.html). Jupyter 'inherits' a lot of features from IPython. In fact, before 'Jupyter notebooks' expanded to handle many kernels and rebranded, they were called 'IPython notebooks', as they added the notebook interface to the IPython console. IPython had added the REPL model to the Python console.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response,so basically everything you can do in script mode you can do in interactive mode?(also big project)